# How do I use an asset and change the material on it without changing all instances of that asset?

Tags: materials

I have tried using make local and make single user, have tried making a user library of assets so I can import using append, anything I do to my asset is also done to all other instances of that asset. I need to change the colour of the asset without changing the other assets